# "Regulatory Stakes" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm a non-native speaker trying to read a economics paper. I have a problem with the meaning of "regulatory stakes". A few examples of the use:

1. "The regulatory stake which is implemented at any given date..."
2. "Since the optimal collusion-proof regulation aims at reducing the social cost of these collusive behaviours, regulatory stakes must be more and more reduced over time."
3. "Reducing the regulatory stake at date k makes less costly the constraints"

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure there is a set term for *regulatory stakes*, but #2 and #3 are translations that cannot serve as examples.

Comment: Was this all from the same paper? Can you provide proper references for your quotes? What language were they translated from? Do you have a copy of the original paper? I'm guessing it is a mistranslation. (I tried to google the source, but it required registration and I don't want to have to give anyone my personal information to read a random paper I know nothing about.)

Comment: @StuartF they are all from the same paper. The paper was written in english. Paper name is: The Life Cycle of Regulatory Agencies: Dynamic Capture and Transaction Costs by David Martimort.

Comment: As I understand the term, it means "the risks attached to the regulation of some aspect life or commerce, in respect to the possible benefits". But here it seems to refer to the amount of commitment to a future regulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a phrase with a special meaning. Its meaning is the normal meaning of "stake" modified by the normal meaning of "regulatory".

A "stake" here means an interest that someone has in the success, failure or operation of some organization or process. "Stakeholders" have a "stake", by definition. It's doesn't just mean an ownership. Anyone who will be affected by the operation has a "stake". A partner with a business has a "stake" in that business even if they don't own any part of it, because the success or failure of the business will affect them.

A "regulatory stake" means an interest that someone has in something because of regulation. For example an environmental watchdog has a stake in a business subject to environmental laws because the watchdog is responsible for ensuring the laws are complied with. It is a "regulatory stake" because regulations give them that stake. Similarly a financial regulator has a "regulatory stake" in a bank.